# Sending commands to an existing screen session?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a Java app running in a screen session (A game server), and I'd like to be able to write a script to send commands to it periodically (with cron probably), but I'm not sure how to send commands to a running screen session.

Is this possible? Might be complicated by the fact that I'm not just sending more shell commands to the screen, but putting text into the running Java console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this example from [screen faq](http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq#i_have_a_nested_screen_session_-_how_do_i_send_screen_commands_to_the_inner_screen):

```
screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'top^M'
```

It will run `top` command in the screen session named `test`.

`^M` is a control character you can put by pressing `CTRL+V, ENTER` in bash.