# Automatically creating a particular screen setup on startup

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Here's my problem :

I have a particular setup with screen that I like to launch on startup, to quickly have access to several programs I use often.

Here's an example :

screen -U -S test -t shell

Within this screen session :

screen -t irc (in which I'll launch irssi)
screen -t process (in which I'll launch top)
...

Note that this result in having **one unique sessions**, and multiple shells in this session.
I specify it, because so far, my tests have brought me to the point where my script creates a screen session, in a session, in a session ... and I can't really figure out why.

I'd like to know if it's possible to build up a script that I could launch to create the whole screen setup and start the programs automatically when executed.

Thanks for any advices. =)

Comment: You mean like `./awesome_startup_script` and then it opens only 1 screen with all the applications you normally use?

Comment: That would be the idea. Basically, it should create one screen session, multiple shells in that sessions, and each shell gets its own program started.

Comment: I would recommend using `tmux` to automatically set up something like this, but that's mostly personal preference, since `screen` should mostly be capable to do the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `~/.screenrc` file containing:

```
defutf8 on
sessionname test
screen -t shell   0
screen -t irc     1 irssi
screen -t process 2 top
```

Then, when you log in to the box, execute

```
screen -DR
```

which detaches any currently running screen and attaches to it, or if no screen is running it creates a new one.

Comment: This worked wonderfully (for me). I didn't think about using the config file, shame on me =/ Thank you for the tip !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen -S sessionname -X command` to run tmux-commands<sup>1</sup> in an existing session, e.g. `-X screen top` to create a new window and run `top` in it. Note that the newly created window will be closed when the command terminates. If you would like to have a shell afterwards, use something like `-X screen sh -c 'ls; bash'`.

There are also ways to run commands in existing screen windows, see these two questions:

- [send command to an already running screen session](https://superuser.com/q/116743/176100)
- [Sending commands to an existing screen session?](https://superuser.com/q/201807/176100)

<sup>1: You can find the complete list of tmux commands on its manpage.</sup>